# PHP preg_replace();

Tags: php, regex

I've got a problem with regexp function, preg_replace(), in PHP.
I want to get viewstate from html's input, but it doesn't work properly.

This code:

```
$viewstate = preg_replace('/^(.*)(<input\s+id="__VIEWSTATE"\s+type="hidden"\s+value=")(.*[^"])("\s+name="__VIEWSTATE">)(.*)$/u','^\${3}$',$html);
```

Returns this:

```
%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%21DOCTYPE+html+PUBLIC+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD+XHTML+1.0+Transitional%2F%2FEN%22+%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fxhtml1%2FDTD%2Fxhtml1-transitional.dtd%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Chtml+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22+%3E%0D%0A%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3E%0D%0A%09Strava.cz%0D%0A%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3Clink+rel%3D%22shortcut+icon%22+href%3D%22..%2FGrafika%2Ffavicon.ico%22+type%3D%22image%2Fx-icon%22+%2F%3E%3Clink+rel%3D%22stylesheet%22+type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22+media%3D%22screen%22+href%3D%22..%2FStyly%2FZaklad.css%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cstyle+type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++.style1%0D%0A++++++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++width%3A+47px%3B%0D%0A++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++++++.style2%0D%0A++++++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++width%3A+64px%3B%0D%0A++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cscript+type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++var+_gaq+%3D+_gaq+%7C%7C+%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A++_gaq.push%28%5B
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I left this question for a long time. Finally I used DOMDocument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I only want to know, why it's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main mistake was the use of funciton `preg_replace`, witch returns the subject - neither the matched pattern nor the replacement. Thank you for your ideas and for the recommendation of DOMDocument. m93a

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-returnvalues

Answer (score 2):

To be sure i'd split this match into two phases:

1. Find the relevant input element
2. Get the value

Because you cannot be certain what the attributes order in the element will be.

```
if(preg_match('/<input[^>]+name="__VIEWSTATE"[^>]*>/i', $input, $match))
    $value = preg_replace('/.*value="([^"]*)".*/i', '$1', $match[0]);
```

And, of course, always consider [`DOM`](http://php.net/dom) and [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/domxpath) over regex for parsing html/xml.

Comment: I can be certain, because the value is the only thing that changes :)
But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should only capture when you're planning on using the data. So most () are obsolete in that regexp pattern. Not a cause for failure but I thought I'd mention it.

Instead of using [^"] to mark that you don't want that character you could use the non-greedy modifier - `?`. This makes sure the pattern is matching as little as it can. Since you have `name="__VIEWSTATE"` following the value this should be safe.

Let's put this in practice and simplify the pattern some. This works as you want:

```
'/.*<input\s+id="__VIEWSTATE"\s+type="hidden"\s+value="(.+?)"\s+name="__VIEWSTATE">.*/'
```

I would [strongly recommend](https://twitter.com/tobiassjosten/status/217317667953057792) checking out [an alternative to regexp](http://phpmaster.com/php-dom-using-xpath/) for DOM operations. This makes certain your code works also if the attributes changes order. Plus it's so much nicer to work with.

Comment: It still doesn't work - I will find an alternative way. Thanks :)